# C# Web Service: Getting product name assembly and machine name where it is executed

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a Web Service in C# that is published to a server on IIS.

In this web service I build a connection string using some parameters.

There are two, "Applicacion Name" and "Workstation Id" that I would like to set them with assembly product name and machine name where web service is executed. So I do that as below:

- To set "Application Name" I use    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName value
- To set "Workstation ID"    I use System.Environment.MachineName value

In Win forms apps I use these values but are they correct when talking about web services? I mean, Are these values extracted in a different way in web services?

Also to avoid using System.Windows.Forms namespace is there any other way to obtain web service application name?

By Application name I mean the product name that appears from visual studio ide when you go to project properties => Application => Assembly information button => Product Name field.

Comment: _"to do it"_ - to do **what**, exactly? If you execute the statements you show, you will get the values from the server, not the client.

Comment: @CodeCaster I want to obtain the values from the server where web service is published on IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the values in app.config file of Web service.

```html
Hi, You can store the values in app.config file of Web service.
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="ValueApplicationName" />
    <add key="WorkstationID" value="ValueWorkstationID" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
When you open the application that connects with web service, The web service can pass this value to the application. Use System.Configuration to read value from config file: 
string AppName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationName"];
```

Comment: I would like to obtain in run time the product name of the assembly regarding to web service.